# Displaying a JLabel text on top of a drawing

Tags: java, swing, jframe, draw, jlabel

i can't figure out how to make this work.

I created a main class, extended in JFrame. 
If I run the program with the draw() and paint() methods to draw something, my label is not visible. If I just run the Main() class without the draw() and paint() methods, it works.

I'm trying to playing around with Swing components but this is really hard (I'm such a noob T.T).

Would you help me, please?

I'd like to see the label on top of my rectangle.

```
public class Main extends JFrame {

    JLabel label;

    public Main() {
         setSize(400, 300);
         setTitle("Title");
         setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
         setLocationRelativeTo(null);
         setVisible(true);

         label = new JLabel("Text inside");
         add(label, BorderLayout.NORTH);
   }

    public void paint(Graphics g){
        Image img = createImage(getWidth(), getHeight());
        Graphics gr = img.getGraphics();
        draw(gr);
        g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, this);
    }

    public void draw(Graphics g){
        g.drawRect(100, 100, 200, 100);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Main start = new Main();
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried calling super.paint()?

Comment: I solved it with super.paint() :D

Answer (score 1):

Couple of things:

1. move your addition of label up before showing your JFrame and add your label to contentPane instead of JFrame directly.
2. Currently your Image is Overlaying everything because the width and height of image is equals to your frame. I am not sure what you are trying to achieve with drawing blank image with a rectangle. you can directly draw your rectangle on JFrame itself.
3. If you intend to set your Image as Background and over it you want to show your label then you need to do it differently. You need to create a JLabel with desired image and add it as contentPane.

Hope these pointers will help you.

Comment: thanks, with your help and the other answers i solved my problem :)

Answer (score 1):

The resolution of your problem is pretty simple. First, you don't need to create an `Image` and use `createImage(getWidth(), getHeight())` on it to create the Graphics. Apart of that, when you *override* a method, you "invalidate" it and "replace" it with your code. Swing uses the `paint(Graphics g)` method to draw the components (like JButtons and JLabels). *Override* it will cause that **your** method is called not swing's. To fix the error, in the `draw(Graphics g)` you simply can write `super.paint(g)` to call the swing's method. So your class will be like this:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class Main extends JFrame {

    JLabel label;

    public Main() {
         setSize(400, 300);
         setTitle("Title");
         setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
         setLocationRelativeTo(null);
         setVisible(true);

         label = new JLabel("Text inside");
         add(label, BorderLayout.NORTH);
   }

    public void paint(Graphics g){
        Image img = createImage(getWidth(), getHeight());
        Graphics gr = img.getGraphics();
        draw(gr);
        g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, this);
    }

    public void draw(Graphics g){
        super.paint(g);
        g.drawRect(100, 100, 200, 100);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Main start = new Main();
    }
}
```